# Prove: If matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ with $m>n$ is full rank and $B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is diagonal, $ABA^H$ is positive semi-definite

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, hermitian-matrices

If matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ with $m>n$ is full rank and $B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is diagonal with $det(B)\ne0$, and $(B)_{ii}>0$ how can we prove that $ABA^H$ is positive semi-definite?

It is easy to show that diagonal matrix $B$ is positive definite.  I also have a hunch that $ABA^H$ is Hermitian, but I have not proven this.  I don't know how to apply either of these facts to shown that $ABA^H$ is positive semi-definite?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is $A^H$, transpose?

Comment: @NDB I mean for $A^H$ to signify the Hermitian transpose such that $A^H=(\bar A)^T$ thanks!

Comment: Can you check the condition on $B$? For example, for $n=1$, $B=(-1)$ and $A$ any $m\times 1$ matrix, you get $ABA^H=-AA^H$, which is negative.

Comment: @AnneBauval my apologies, I needed to specify that the diagonal elements of $B$ are positive.  I have made this edit.

Comment: @NDB as I mentioned in my comment to Anne, I forgot to specify that the diagonal elements of $B$ are positive.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Note that $x^HABA^Hx=(A^Hx)^HB(A^Hx)$ is $y^HBy$ for some vector $y$ that happens to be $A^Hx$. If the components of (the diagonal of) $B$ are $b_1,...,b_n$ and of $y$ are $y_1,...,y_n$, then $y^HBy=\sum_{i=1}^nb_i|y_i|^2\geq0$.

Comment: @NDB, ah I see what you're getting at.  This makes sense.  So do I also need to prove that $ABA^H$ is Hermitian?  I have not actually proven this yet.

Comment: What you have to prove depends on what you can assume known. Based on the properties of $^H$ you have $(ABA^H)^H=(A^H)^HB^HA^H=ABA^H$

Comment: @NDB I see.  Thank you so much, I think that answers my question.  If you put this all in the answer I can accept your answer as the solution.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

$ A : \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow  \mathbb{C}^m $,
$ A^H : \mathbb{C}^m \rightarrow  \mathbb{C}^n $

We need to show that $ <ABA^H x, x > \; \geq \; 0 $ for any $ x \in  \mathbb{C}^m $, where $<,>$ denotes the standard Hermitian dot product on $\mathbb{C}^n$. We have
$ <ABA^H x, x > \; = \;  <BA^H x, A^H x > \; = 
\sum_{i=1}^n B_{ii}y_i \bar{y}_i $ where $y_i$are coordinates of $A^Hx$.  This sum is non-negative, because all $ B_{ii} > 0 $